# Portable Python 2.7.3.2 PyScripter

Tags: python, portability, pyscripter

I'm trying to use Portable Python 2.7.3.2, when I try to write a script using the PyScripter, it is throwing error and it is really annoying with scripting using this IDE.

When i try to type `import os` using the console window, it automatically takes `import oTraceback (most recent call last):` and throws an error as below:

```
File "D:\Matt\Portable Python 2.7.3.2\App\lib\inspect.py", line 365, in getdoc
    if not isinstance(doc, types.StringTypes):
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'StringTypes'
```

[image: Error Message Snapshot]

Comment: The line 365 in inspect.py should be `if not isinstance(doc, types.StringType):`. Notice that `StringType` is _without_ the trailing `s`

Comment: so the inspect.py should be updated!!!